# Job: offer the ability to suppress companies and recruiters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

For various reasons, I may not want to see ads from a particular company.  Examples are

- I've worked there before and they have a no-rehire policy
- I work there now
- I already interviewed there.

Similarly, I may want to filter certain recruiting companies.

Can you please add the ability to filter these results?

Comment: Generally speaking we want to put candidates in control, and this _does_ fit in nicely. Let me check into this a bit.

Comment: +1 I don't want to see any job offers from Crossover

Comment: Any traction on this? It's almost a necessity now.

Comment: @IanKemp coming soon! See updated answer below.

Answer (score 15):

Update: you can filter out companies in your search results by using the 'companies to exclude' filter

[image: Screenshot of the search filter dialog. The "Company" tab is selected and the new "Companies to exclude" option is listed second, under "Companies to include".]

---

Edit: the ability to filter out companies in your search results is coming soon. We are in the final build phases of our job search feature.

---

This is a good idea.  We'll have to give this more thought. I'm not sure yet how we'd implement it and its not yet on the roadmap so I'm setting this to deferred.

Comment: You can ensure that companies have their own profiles (and internally ask them for their legal identifier / serial number as part of the KYB process) then users can block based on that.

Comment: @Donna so is this upcoming feature just about filtering search results?  What about the job advertisements?  Will it hide those as well?

Comment: @psubsee2003 this feature is just for filtering search results (it's live now). [There's a separate request to hide companies in job ads](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338003/global-dismiss-and-never-show-again-button-for-companies).

Comment: @Donna which is why I asked.  Also because http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317756/ignore-companies-when-seeing-jobs is dup of this question but your solution doens't address it at all.  Can you change the dup to the new feature request?

Comment: Can we have a blog post about this feature? At +34 votes and so many duplicates, it seems to be a fan favourite.

Comment: Two years have passed and I don't see this capability.

Comment: @einpoklum I've updated this answer to include the company exclusion filter.