# Ignore companies when seeing jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I live in a small country and there are very few local software companies. One of them has a really bad reputation (in terms of being a terrible place to work and an overall cancer on the software engineering society) and yet is very visible - I see their job ads every time I visit Stack Overflow.

This rather leaves a bad aftertaste to my Stack Overflow visiting experience. The company is associated with negative emotions and I have no desire to have it have a presence in my world, yet it is there every time I open the page.

An "ignore jobs by this company" that would make these ads disappear would allow me to eliminate this negative factor from my Stack Overflow user experience.

This mainly affects me on the front-page experience (as opposed to when searching for jobs).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312795/job-offer-the-ability-to-suppress-companies-and-recruiters

Comment: Better duplicate, although a new feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338003/global-dismiss-and-never-show-again-button-for-companies