# Dismissed jobs reappear often

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I have hidden (clicked on dismiss) this job at least 10 times already:

[image]

Is this a bug or is the company actually republishing the same job over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the employer keeps reposting the job, then it's always a different job to us...

BUT... as of today can dismiss the company page. When you do so, we will not show you any listings from that company.

If you wanted to do that, you could visit [the company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/coolblue), and scroll down to the bottom of it. There you will see a button to dismiss it.

There's one caveat though... new jobs may appear for up to 24 hours on ads.

Comment: I have changed the accepted answer since this is ultimately what I was looking for. Thank you for the feature! Company already dismissed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto excellent! I'll mark it as [meta-tag:status-completed] then.

Comment: Should this dismissal be once per account or is it stored in cookies? If it should be once, then I hit a bug

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto when you dismiss a job, we store that in the db. It should be persistent across sessions / different browsers as long as you are logged in. If you found a bug, please create another question with tags [meta-tag:jobs] and [meta-tag:bugs]

Answer (score 11):

I looked into this, and it actually does look like this particular job is being re-posted. I found 6 separate job ads with the name "Tech Lead C#" posted by that company (of which I could see you've already dismissed 5).

We're currently working on a way for users to indicate that they don't want to see any jobs from a particular company, so that would mitigate this particular issue, but we're not quite there yet. In the meantime, unfortunately you will have to continue to manually dismiss jobs individually.

Comment: Thanks! I was going to post a feature request for hiding companies entirely, so you saved that extra step

Comment: Maybe someone from the team can shoot them a message, indicating that this kind of behaviour might be counterproductive?