# Dismissed company job ads reappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

This is a followup to [Dismissed jobs reappear often](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364735/dismissed-jobs-reappear-often/).

On Wednesday 28/3 I dismissed the company as outlined by @g3rv4♦, and I see this at the company page:

[image]

I did so at my home's computer, but I hadn't seen ads from that company anymore, not even at my work's computer. Notice that I have dismissed every job I've seen from them.
When I got to work today, that changed:

[image]

Why did I get to see ads from that company again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dismissed Company Pages has been implemented in our Ad Server. If you dismissed a company page, you will not see any Company Page Ads for that company, nor for any jobs that are affiliated specifically with that Company Page.

Note that due to our data model, it's not *required* that a Job posting be affiliated with a company page. For those jobs, you will still need to dismiss them specifically, either on `stackoverflow.com/jobs` or by dismissing the ad for that particular job.

<strike>Note: We currently do not expose a way to dismiss a company page directly from a Company Page *Ad*. That feature will be forthcoming, so for now you will need to click through to that Company Page and manually dismiss it from there.</strike>

You can now dismiss Company Pages directly from Company Page Ads:

[image: Company Page Ad Dismiss Button]

This action is synced with Stack Overflow Jobs, so if you dismiss a company page ad:

- You will not see any company page ads for that company
- The company will not return in any search results or recommendations
- You will not see any job ads for that company
- Job ads for that company will not return in any search results or recommendations
- We will not include any of that company's jobs in any emails we send you

As dismissing a company page ad affects the *company*, this means that you won't see any of that company's current job listings, *nor future* job listings.