# Is this intentional that the ad sidebar displays all positions from the same employer?

Tags: support, advertising

This is what I periodically see on my side bar:

[image]

Do you think the algorithm for selecting positions, can be improved, so it does not display all line items from the same employer? Or is this intentional?

Comment: The ads are geo-mapped, so it might be that from where you are logged in, the algorithm only found these ads. This happened to me as well when I was in Saudi Arabia, all the ads shown were from an employer in Iran (oddly, I didn't see those ads when I log in from my normal location, which is Kuwait).  Crossover itself is one of those companies that posts positions everywhere. I have seen their ads on other networks for the same position in different countries/cities.

Comment: Just FYI, there was recently a [concern raised about this particular employer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317896/the-crossover-job-ads-have-a-funny-smell). So even though it seems like there are no other jobs available in your area, you might want to look a little harder. :)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319446

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it intentional, but it is the result of an ever-changing ad-selection algorithm. There was a recent change which made remote-only jobs considered a much better match for a large number of people. Unfortunately, there aren't very many remote-only jobs in the system right now, and if you combine that with a location where we don't have a lot of traditional office jobs, then you're likely to get what you got here.

As I said, we're constantly working on the algorithm, and feedback about edge cases like this are good. We're going to be making some short-term changes to help mitigate this, including treating jobs that *offer* remote similar to those which are remote-*only*, and *several* longer-term changes:

- Giving people more control over what locations they want to see ads for
- Treating jobs that offer relocation and/or visa sponsorship as special
- Trying to learn how distance may be more or less important in certain countries and across certain country boundaries.
- Other things, some known and some unknown at this time

I don't think disallowing showing multiple ads for the same company is necessarily the right answer, but we'll consider it.

We have also recently started imposing a scoring penalty on ads that you've seen many times, so the more times you've seen a particular job ad, the less likely you are to see it the next day. Doesn't mean you *won't* see it tomorrow, just means it's less likely.

Hopefully that more or less answered your question.