# Strange "Want a [skill] job?" Ad

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I find it strange (and depressing) to see the job ad asking if you want a job for a specific skill but showing other skill instead. Like the one below. After clicking to see the detail, yes it tells you that the company wants you to know C++, and the jobs were tagged with C++, but at the first glance it feel quite sad for someone who is looking for a job.

[image: Want a c++ job? ad]

Comment: You couldn't *pay* me 30k to write lisp.  Those parenthesis...

Comment: 6 to 8 wee^H^H^Hmonths: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317896/the-crossover-job-ads-have-a-funny-smell

Comment: This is by-design right now. The employer tagged their listing with those tags, and they seem correct. Maybe the title of the job would more accurately be "Lisp / C++ Software Engineer" or "Java / C++ engineer"?

Comment: @DavidFullerton: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rSXke.png - they have Java + C++ titled job adds. This just looks like tag spam.

Comment: @Mat Those seem to be slightly different jobs? The [Lisp job](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104276/lisp-software-engineer-30k-crossover) does mention C++ in the skills they're looking for. It's not a great job listing, but they do seem to be looking for Lisp/C++ developers.

Comment: @DavidFullerton: for the Lisp one maybe, crappy title if that is the case. For the "Java Architect" one, either they really screwed up their title and they meant "JVM architect" or they're _missing_ a bunch of tags (that adds also mentions sh/python/jython/perl). I don't know if there's anything to fix on SE's side, but that's bad/annoying targeting.

Comment: @JAL I think that is exactly what they are offering to do.

Comment: Folks these are jobs you don't want...move along.

Comment: Maybe they want you to cross over to another programming language.

Comment: I am disappointed.  I expected to see a complaint about a job posting tagged with [skill].  That said, I have successfully flagged job postings that spam tags in the past (jobs tagged with [LanguageX] as a way to lure in "good" developers, but don't actually do any LanguageX programming).

Comment: Crossover is a sleazy employer. Period. They abuse Jobs and SE does nothing about that. (No, not Steve Jobs - he's beyond their reach)

Comment: @DeerHunter Do you have a source about the sleazy thing ? I am interested. Edit: Ok after a quick search I found what I was looking for

Comment: @bviale - a spate of recent complaints at meta SO - some have company name redacted away.

Comment: @bviale - I'd say they're pretty sleasy when the first line of one of their [job advertisements](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/111339/product-manager-100k-crossover?searchTerm=crossover&offset=17) insults you

Comment: @Sayse Hilarious typo I have to admit

Comment: @bviale - just you wait until they offer 'want a brainf**k job?' advert.

Comment: I tried them, their Java test is really serious. But it's offtopic I guess...

Comment: Related discussion about them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264115/there-seems-to-be-a-fake-company-on-careers

Comment: @DeerHunter I'll take it!