# Since when have agents been allowed?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I always understood that only employers could post jobs, yet [this job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/114837/net-developer-hays-specialist-recruitment?med=clc&ref=large-sidebar-orange-looking) is posted by an agent that is hiding the details of the employer.

When and why did Stack Overflow decide to go back on their commitment?

Comment: There is a "flag a problem" button on every job listing you can use. We can only stop something if you tell us about it.

Comment: "Specialist Recruitment" is not enough of a hint to tip off the sales person perhaps.  Compare to [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317896/the-crossover-job-ads-have-a-funny-smell), definitely an agent and currently posting 24 jobs..

Comment: If the sales person gets any sort of commission, they are no better then agents themselfs!    As the job advert contains words like "my client" clearly the sale person that approved it it did not care.

Comment: I don't think SO approve each ad individually. That just wouldn't scale.

Comment: TZHX is correct. Customer can purchase and publishing listings without ever talking to a rep.

Comment: @Juice, I thought part of the deal with the users was that all adverts would be checked by a person and that is would verified the person placing the add is acting for the employer.

Comment: @IanRingrose Our ad sales team does have to manually approve new advertisements from clients before they ever get put into the ad rotation. But that's a different product and a different team - it's not related to job postings.

Comment: Are there [agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Smith) on Stack Overflow now?

Comment: *L'histoire se répète* https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/writing/rant.html

Comment: @Tunaki he he, we should stop the "agents" getting into the matrix(SO) at all costs ;)

Comment: *"all adverts would be checked by a person"* that would cost maybe $1500 per listing, it will never happen

Comment: @JoeBlow why does it take more then 1hr to check an advert?   Given the standard wages of a **good** admin person is £10 per hour, that is a lot less then $1500!!!

Comment: hey Ian, actually running customer-service -like departments is mindbogglingly expensive.  example: you can lookup online how much KYC costs banks per account. another way to look at it; at any headhunter look at the cost of 1x team and how many (few) accounts they can keep track of annually.  it's absolutely inconceivable SO will ever apply any "checking", it's just another web site selling posts. they can no more check anything that google can check ads or "tripadvisor" can check reviews you know.

Comment: {In any event the specific answer to your question here would seem to be "go ahead and flag it" - and fair enough.  if SO plan to try to follow up on such flags, God Bless.}

Comment: We are clean / don't ask / I'm an agent

Comment: @IanRingrose: $10/hr for the person's wage perhaps, but a whole lot more goes into it than that. That person needs a place to work, a building, with rent, and electricity. He needs a phone and a computer, which then implies IT staff to support all that. The costs begin to spiral. It's never about just handing a guy $10 bucks.

Comment: This is _way_ too accusatory. Tell me, what're the odds that Stack Overflow is allowing agents on Jobs, compared to the odds of, say, someone skirting the rules and hoping not to get noticed?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I have pulled down all of their listings. They're very much NOT following our rules. We've disabled their access until we can reach out and talk to the customer.

Comment: Why don't you simply allow "agents" - - but, ensure they are indicated as such?

Comment: and indeed charge agents more, as any advertising service does.

Comment: Agents add no value, but waste everyone's time, apply pressure and obscure things. They're a curse on everyone. Please don't.

Comment: @Flexo thank you. They constantly post jobs that don't exist just to fish out candidates.

Comment: Not to forget that they go on and spam your Inbox with 'openings'

Comment: That, and I never met an agent/recruiter that actually knew anything about technology. As a result, they either throw things at you that have zero relevance to your skillset or on the other side of the coin, on the business-side, they throw candidates at you that have no clue how to do anything.

Comment: Sorry to hijack, but does this also apply to recruitment agents hunting for candidates? So not posting jobs, but sending messages to job seekers.

Comment: @DavidG It's situational. We allow recruiters, but when they message you they have to disclose the client and be a specific position. If it's just general solicitation, let us know, that's against our TOS.

Comment: @Juice This one was about "opportunities" in my area. How do I let you know? There's no option to flag a message and I can't click on the company name.

Comment: You can email careers @StackOverflow.com or post in meta.