# How do I exclude job posts from Crossover when searching?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I noticed that whenever I search for any job I'm always presented with a ton of job openings from a company called Crossover. I'm not interested in that company and would like to exclude it from my search results.

Is it possible to modify the search query to exclude all posts from that company?

Comment: Are you in the US or the EU? If so you should not be seeing these ads. See [The 'Crossover' job ads have a funny smell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319238)