# How can I remove Crossover from my emailed "occasional jobs"?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, spam, email

It is possible to remove companies such as Crossover from the [standard searches](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332917/how-do-i-exclude-job-posts-from-crossover-when-searching). However, I'm also getting emails *You're receiving this email because you are opted in to Stack Overflow emails highlighting jobs and companies.*

Some of these entries are interesting but they are drowned out by the Crossover flood of implausible ads (the latest silliness is showing an $800K exec position advertised with a C++ tag!).

Either SO should allow for adding an exclusion filter that also covers those emails or should finally do something about Crossover.

Comment: Agreed. Especially when they refresh the same 5 or so jobs every other week so they look "new".

Comment: This isn't the first time I've heard negatives about Crossover, why hasn't anything been done about them?

Comment: @Script47 Because of bs ridiculous excuses like _"We cannot judge who is supposed to be banned from Jobs"_ **WRONG!** If You really want to prove, that You care enough to be even slightly better then any other job aggregate sites out there; If  You really want to show us, that You care about the actual **quality** of service You _pretend_ to build here, It's Your duty to step in and have actual what it takes to take a stand against **predatory** and **shady** business practices that everyone knows happens inside those companies. But it will obviously pure tabu, because You know... **$$$** ♥

Comment: Related: [SO careers should stop accepting business from predatory employers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332037/so-careers-should-stop-accepting-business-from-predatory-employers)

Comment: @L_Church As I read the question, the 800K is just an example. The real problem is one company posting so much, that openings from other companies get drowned out. I recall a lot of recruitment companies doing that on job boards, back in the day - effectively making these job boards useless.

Comment: Ahhh i understand now.. Thanks for the clear up. I do agree they are clogging up the board with their "new" jobs

Comment: Related: [Emails based on job preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367598/emails-based-on-job-preferences) - possibly including an answer

Comment: We also need to point out that a wage of 800k/year is a monthly wage of 66,666.66... Something fishy going on here

Comment: Trust the church to bring that up  ;-)

Comment: No need to be beastly :-)

Comment: @L_Church indeed, it clearly shouldn't be C++ but PHP

Comment: Wait you're not earning 800k already?

Comment: Wouldn't this churning of jobs be considered a sign of bad faith, and a misuse of Jobs?  Based on Tim's post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332279/1197934), they need to be looked at rather closely to see if they're actually using the system properly and in good faith.  If not, refund 'em and get rid of 'em.

Comment: Do they actually pay that much, and that too as remote, because all the crossover job postings i have seen have the remote tag, it just looks like a spam. They even have videos of executives ( earning $400K according to website ),  who boast about company culture. Does SO actually verifies the postings, and the **money**?

Comment: @jokerster From everything I've read, crossover uses these postings (that have long since been filled or never existed to start with) to get people to register with them.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Update**: you can now exclude specific companies on your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current). Once excluded, you shouldn't receive job recommendations for that company (job ads, emails, etc).

---

You can dismiss Crossover as a company. That will make it so that their listings are not shown on your search results, ads or emails we send you.

In order to do so you should:

1. Go to [their company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/crossover)
2. Click on the extended actions menu on top right (the three dots)
3. Click on "Dismiss"

If after doing so you still receive emails with Crossover listings, please report them as a bug (including the email title on your report).

Comment: Finally!  Feel bad for the poor souls that actually apply for this company without know what they are all about.  Sad that SO allows them to keep posting on the Jobs site.  Really brings down the quality of the entire platform :-(

Comment: I have now pre-emptively done this even though I don't think I've seen them show up in my email.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Can you tell us in short what they are about? I mean I never applied but often thought why their jobs looked so tasty.

Comment: @Chani - I haven't applied either but there are countless stories online from current/former employees.  Some of the highlights that I read: you are under webcam surveillance the entire time you are working, they monitor your keyboard/mouse activity and if they decide you didn't use them enough, you aren't paid for that time, you need to clock out when you use the bathroom, when you are learning something new related to a project you are working on you need to clock out, entire teams fired with one days notice - the list goes on and on and on.  There is a seemingly endless supply of horrors...

Comment: Assuming all of the above is true SO is showing a real lack of integrity by allowing them to use the platform

Comment: @Chani this company has been [discussed many times over here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=crossover)

Comment: @AbeMiessler  Who cares about the _integrity_ when You'd have to waive all the **$$$** ♥.  I wouldn't mind that if they were **open** and **honest** about that. (we all know the situation is tragic indeed - new invasive ads etc). It's like McDonald's trying to convince You that they're a core of any well balanced diet. Cute.

Comment: How do I report the bug - I've dismissed Crossover, but I still see in my email from a saved search.

Comment: @Rakesh create a new question on meta, tag it with [meta-tag:jobs] and [meta-tag:bug]. Please include the email subject and the dismissed company ;)

Comment: Is this still working? I successfully followed this process for Crossover a few months ago. I just tried to do the same for another company, but the option no longer appears to be there for me on any company page.

Comment: @NeilSlater yes! it’s still working but it has moved. Now, we have three dots on the header (the placement at the button was... the way we had to ship it without having a good design for it). You should see three dots that let you dismiss it. Let me know if you can’t find it and I’ll add a screenshot (I’m mobile now)

Comment: @g3rv4 Thanks, that worked.

Comment: Beware that this is permanent, for now. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365674/allow-me-to-undismiss-a-company

Answer (score 56):

Users ought to be able to downvote employers. After a few downvotes, the system should start to make their listing less prominent, and maybe stop emailing it. After a lot, it should kick them out altogether. If the same employer makes a new account, someone will notice and ought to be able to flag it as spam.

Comment: +1 , with appropriate safeguards against abuse

Comment: Employers pay money to advertise on SO Jobs, right? So making a new account isn't that simple. On the flip side, it means they probably paid to use the service for a set amount of time, so you can't easily ban them, either.

Comment: @S.L.Barth probably terms of service should somehow prevent employers from abusing the advertising channels provided by Stack Exchange platform (I wouldn't be surprised though if current terms allow them to spam indiscriminately. "Everything you want for your money!")

Comment: @gnat Judging by the question, the massive posting is drowning out the advertisement by other paying companies. It's not wise to let a single customer adversely affect _all_ of one's other customers. SO does have an interest in handling this.

Comment: agree @S.L.Barth - that's a very good point. Could be the case when indiscriminate greediness damages the business

Comment: @S.L.Barth Presumably the contracts have a renewal date - accumulated downvotes/flags could easily impact their ability to renew, or require them to have a human review prior to renewal.

Comment: This spam does not just drown other advertisers, it also taints them.