# Dismissed company still appears in Inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I recently dismissed the company Crossover from jobs as suggested in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369321/2740086) meta post. Today I got a "New Jobs on Stack Overflow" email that contained 9 Crossover jobs. I cannot find Crossover jobs on the job board but they are still lurking in my inbox. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I blame caching.

Comment: Yep, there's a bug here; we're respecting job dismissals but not company dismissals in job alert emails. I'm fixing it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We were respecting company dismissals in all our other emails except this one. I've made the necessary changes and given it a test run and all looks well.

Fix is building out to prod now. Thanks for the heads up!