# Still Recieving Email for Jobs by Crossover

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm still getting Jobs email alerts for Crossover-Ads, according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369321/5072526) answer I'm filing a bug Report.
I'm not interested in their Job-Offers and I don't want to see them anymore.

- I've already dismissed Crossover on their company page (If i remember right, I did that on 11. June 2018), it now says

> Okay, you won’t see this company anymore. Undo

- Company: Crossover
- Email-Subject: "New jobs on Stack Overflow"
- Job-Alert: "Remote java jobs in Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland (within 100 km) "
- Email-Date: 2018-06-17 01:24:37.35606449 +0000 UTC

Comment: This issue was [fixed yesterday by Dean](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369640/920295) at 4pm UTC (after you received this email), so I'm closing this one as a dupe, but if you see it again, please post a new question with the same tags. Thanks!