# Where can I see which companies I dismissed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

As you can see in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369321/3233388), you can dismiss a company from jobs.

I dismissed several when I first saw that answer and now I'd like to revise the list.

Where can I see which companies I dismissed?