# How to remove company ads on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising, jobs-messages

Recently, I started getting job ads from an online casino on the jobs section on Stack Overflow. I find the idea of running an Online Casino morally reprehensible, but fine, I can just remove the ad from my feed. Shortly afterwards, however, an ad for the same company starts appearing instead, but now I can't remove it and have to see it every time I go on the site. Is there a way to remove it, without blocking the jobs section completely?

Comment: You're talking about the ad which has has a little logo on top of a blurry image background?

Comment: I'm finding the [Crossover](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317896/the-crossover-job-ads-have-a-funny-smell) ads much more reprehensible. No way to work around them, other than using some ad blocker, I suppose

Comment: I would be mostly interested in learning a method to avoid these ads, too.

Comment: I don't use adblockers on this computer, I visit same websites again and again, stackoverflow is one of them, and there doesn't seem like to be any tricks yet.. :(