# Job advertisements should not include current employers (linked company pages)

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I have added myself to the "who you will work with" section on my [company's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/allegro) in stackexchange jobs. We recently updated a job offer and now whenever I visit stackoverflow, it's one of the top spots in the right column, right under "Want a java job?" (`java` is one of my favortie tags and also a tag I have some reputation in).

It's nice stackoverflow thinks I'm a good match for my current job, but I wouldn't expect high click-through-rates for ads which advertise a company the user is already working for. One possible case where it might make sense is someone looking for a different position within the company but I think in practice it would be rare for such a person to not know about the job offer anyway.

So, I suppose this is a bug, and companies whose pages are linked to a user's account should not be advertised to that user.

Comment: The only way to be aware of the job offer in that scenario would be manual observation... wouldn't a nice automated reminder be nice there?

Comment: I am almost certain this is not a bug, but it is by design.  There was never a way to "filter" the jobs.  Looks like there is a new feature coming to allow that to work for search, but doesn't appear to work for advertisements: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312795/job-offer-the-ability-to-suppress-companies-and-recruiters

Answer (score 0):

> One possible case where it might make sense is someone looking for a different position within the company but I think in practice it would be rare for such a person to not know about the job offer anyway.

From the perspective of a small or may be even a medium sized company, I might agree, but what about people who work for large companies?  The company I work for is international and has more than 175K employees.  There are hundreds of jobs open at any time.  Except those in my own department, I rarely know about specific openings unless I go search the internal job board, which I might not do unless I am actively looking or I know of a specific opening that I am interested in.

So to make a blanket "hide listings from my current employer" rule would be doing a disservice to some potential internal candidates while reducing the clutter for others.

So I disagree that we should automatically hide them, but the solution might to make this a user option to hide listings from certain employers including your own so that way you can help limit which employers you see advertisements for.

Comment: Doesn't your company post internal listings somewhere? Wouldn't that be more effective for an internal employee applying to an internal job posting than waiting for it to get posted externally and then applying via that route?

Comment: @Andy ideally yes, but I addressed that in my answer.  If I'm not actively looking for a new role, I might only check in every once in a while.  Whereas a new position that suits me might open up and I'm not aware of it.  Point is, automatically filtering only because I work there does work for some people, not for others.  I think users should be able to control what they see