# Filtering out certain kinds of jobs from unsolicited ads

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, filtering

(I hope this is the right site, otherwise please migrate the question)

Is it possible to filter out certain jobs, which you know apriori you are not interested in, from the ads that are placed on your profile page and other unsolicited locations?

Specifically, I don't want to work for a certain company for moral/political reasons. Or because I don't like their logo, doesn't matter. But - I keep getting ads about working there - which are keeping potentially valid ads from my view.

This question:

[Job: offer the ability to suppress companies and recruiters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312795/job-offer-the-ability-to-suppress-companies-and-recruiters?rq=1)

seems to be about search results.

Comment: Thanks for the feature request... it makes me really happy to see it and be able to tell you that... we're working on it! ETA: 6-8 weeks (but hopefully less)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can [exclude companies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373478/stack-overflow-jobs-update-august-2018) in your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) which will ensure that you don't receive job recommendations or ads for jobs at that company.